# Window maximization icon not visible after perspective change

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I took over an RCP application from an colleague which I will maintain from now on. I found a bug where the window maximization button disappears after an perspective change, before the change everything looks normal. This behavior is not wanted and the maximization button should stay where it was :-).

[image]

but after I switched the perspective the maximization button disappeared

[image]

I'm not very familiar with RCP so I have no idea where to look. The only source code, which is related, which I found is the handler which seems to manage the perspective change.

```
import org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Named;

import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.CanExecute;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.MPerspective;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.MPerspectiveStack;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MWindow;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService;

public class SwitchPerspectiveHandler {
    @CanExecute
    boolean canExecute(MPerspective perspective, @Named("********.command.2.perspective") String perspectiveId) {
        return !perspective.getElementId().equals(perspectiveId);
    }

    @Execute
    void execute(EPartService partService, MPerspective current, MWindow window, @Named("********.command.2.perspective") String perspectiveId) {
        MPerspectiveStack stack = (MPerspectiveStack) window.getChildren().get(0);
        for (MPerspective p : stack.getChildren()) {
            if (perspectiveId.equals(p.getElementId())) {
                String ABC_VIEW_VISIBLE = "abc_view_visible";
                boolean abc_view_visible = false;
                IEclipseContext ctx = window.getContext();
                if (p.getElementId().equals("abcperspective")) {
                    abc_view_visible = true;
                }
                ctx.set(ABC_VIEW_VISIBLE, abc_view_visible);

                partService.switchPerspective(p);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also looked into the application.e4xmi but I can't find anything which tells the perspective to change its decoration.